# Android. Animation Performance

Tags: android, performance, animation

I am using an animation that makes a flip (on `ImageView`), but animation works not smooth (looks like performance issue). The image is a PNG file of size 128x128.

Here I will post code of my animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
                android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillEnabled="false"
    />
</set>
```

I also want to emphasize that the containing view can have up to eight such `ImageViews` (which are also scaled).

Could you please provide me with any advice that can improve animation performance ?

Comment: Are you testing it in the emulator or on a real device? The physical devices have some hardware acceleration that the emulator doesn't, so that might help.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to personally try it on a real device first, but may be the hardware acceleration that fixed is talking about could possibly be your problem.